# Constant key size with categories of different heights

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a chart in which the variable mapped to `fill` contains newlines (or would be too long to put into a legend without them). However, this causes the associated key to have a height mapped to the 'height' of the paragraph for the category. Min reprex:

```
library(ggplot2)

  ggplot(data.frame(x = 1, y = 2, fill = c("a\na\na", "b")), 
         aes(x, y, fill = fill)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

I'd like the key for `a\na\na` category to have the same height as the key for `b`. I tried adjusting `legend.key.height` in `theme`, but that seems to only set the *minimum* height of the keys; it does not reduce key heights.

Comment: I have yet to wrap my head around `ggplot2` syntax, but I did some manipulation of key size with the `guides` function: `guides(fill=guide_legend(title.position="top", keywidth=0.2, keyheight=0.2, default.unit="inch"))`. This may be a different method of the accessing `legend.key.height` you mention.

Comment: what about the padding between the boxes when you change the size? you can do this manually with `g1 <- ggplotGrob(p1); g1$grobs[[8]][[1]][[1]][[4]][4] <- unit(.5, 'cm'); grid::grid.draw(g1)` but the text can overlap